# ¿Como crear un árbol binario al pasar un array como parámetro?

Tags: javascript, array, árboles-binarios

EJERCICIO 7
Implementar la función generateBST para que a partir de un array recibido como parámetro
genere un BinarySearchTree. Devolver dicho árbol generado.
Ejemplo:

```
array(16,6,23,2,17,31,14,5);
```

Cuando paso un valor string o número si me guarda; pero cuando paso un array no, solo guarda el primero que es donde inicia el árbol(16).

Este es mi código:

```js
function generateBST(array) {
  this.value = array[0];
  this.left = null;
  this.rigth = null;
  let i = 1;
  while (i < array.length) {
    this.insert(array[i]);
    i++;
  }

}

generateBST.prototype.insert = function(value) {
  if (this.value > value) {
    if (!this.left) this.left = new generateBST(value);
    else this.left.insert(value);
  } else if (this.value < value) {
    if (!this.rigth) this.rigth = new generateBST(value);
    else this.rigth.insert(value);
  }
}
```

Comment: Deberías llamar a `this.insert(array[i])` dentro del `while`

Comment: hola, si lo intente , pero tampoco me guarda

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El error se debe a que cuando creas los árboles a la izquierda y derecha les estás pasando un valor, cuando deberías pasarle un arreglo.

Corrigiendo esto, el árbol se genera correctamente.

#### Ejemplo:

```js
function generateBST(array) {
  this.value = array[0];
  this.left = null;
  this.rigth = null;
  let i = 1;
  while (i < array.length) {
    this.insert(array[i]);
    i++;
  }
}

generateBST.prototype.insert = function(value) {
  if (this.value > value) {
    if (!this.left) this.left = new generateBST([value]); // <- pasamos un arreglo
    else this.left.insert(value);
  } else if (this.value < value) {
    if (!this.rigth) this.rigth = new generateBST([value]); // <- pasamos un arreglo
    else this.rigth.insert(value);
  }
}

let tree = new generateBST([16,6,23,2,17,31,14,5]);
console.log(JSON.stringify(tree, null, 2));
```